# How to Get the AAD group member?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How to get the Group members list in the OutLook by using Azure Active directory. I already registered my application in Azure portal. I am newbie to this Azure API. 
My problem is to get the Particular group`s members list by C#.

I have Application, Client ID, Object ID, Tenant ID, URI, Client secret. But I do not know that how to use it?

My aim is If I give the group Mail ID means the Group List should be displayed!

Answer (score 5):

We can use the Azure AD Graph to list the members of a specific group, you can check the REST from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#GetGroupMembers).

We can use the **Client Credentials flow** to authenticate with Azure AD which doesn't require users interaction. And to use the Azure AD Graph with **Client Credentials flow**, we need to grant the **application permission** to the app first like below:

[image]

Here is the code samples to print the members using this flow for your reference:

Install the Active Directory Authentication Library:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

Install Microsoft Azure Active Directory Graph Library:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
    string tenantId = "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
    string clientId = "";
    string secret = "";

    authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
    Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;

    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));
    var groupFetcher = (IGroupFetcher)activeDirectoryClient.Groups.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First(g => g.Mail == "group1@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com");
    var membersResult = groupFetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync().Result;
    PrintMembers(membersResoult);

    while (membersResoult.MorePagesAvailable)
    {
        membersResoult = membersResoult.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
        PrintMembers(membersResult);
    }
  
    Console.ReadLine();

}

static void PrintMembers(IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pageCollection)
{
    foreach (var member in pageCollection.CurrentPage)
    {
        var user = member as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User;
        if (user != null)
            Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
        else
        {
            var groupMember = member as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;
            Console.WriteLine(groupMember.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update( append code to show the claims in the token)

Install the package to help decode token(install-package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt)

```
string accessToken = "";
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(accessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

foreach (var claim in tokenS.Claims)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Subject}:{claim.Value}");
}
```

Comment: *Result.CurrentPage.First(g => g.ObjectId == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")* Here ObjectId represent for Group ID?

Comment: Yes. We can also replace it with group name like `g.DisplayName == "group1"`.

Comment: How can I get the group ID?
I have only Group Mail ID! :-(

Comment: To use the group mail ID, we can using the code like `g => g.Mail == "group1@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"`

Comment: I tried both Object ID and mail ID. But I get the exception `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}`

Comment: The error message indicates that you didn't have the permission to access the groups. Have you grant the permission as the figure like in the post? We can check the permission of token by decode it from this [site](https://jwt.io/). It should contain the `scp` or `roles` claim about the permissions. We should see the `Directory.Read.All` roles if you confided the permission as in the post. More detail about the permission, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).

Comment: I registered my app in the ADD but I don`t know why it's happening? Also, I **Grant Permissions** in the path of <My application> ->setting -> required permission. But Still I facing this problem!

Comment: What's the `scop` or `roles` claim in the token?

Comment: Admin `s token I using

Comment: Not able to understand exactly. Did you mean you were login using the admin of your tenant? Also please share the `scope` or `roles` claim in the token, it is very helpful to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Yeah! I am using an admin account for my tenant. I do not know what is meant by `scope` or `roles`. Can you guide me to find it?

Comment: You can parse the token from this [site](https://jwt.io/) and check these claims.

Comment: As per our company policies, I wouldn`t use our instances accessing data in public domain.  :-(

Comment: The token is base64 encode string, we can use the code decode it ourselves. I have update the post to append the code for your reference.